# Usual Arithmetic Conversions: unexpected output

Tags: c, type-conversion

```
signed short Temp;
Temp = 0xF2C9;
Temp2 = 0x100;

unsigned char a;
a = (unsigned char)(Temp/((unsigned short)Temp2));
```

What will be the expected output?
As per my understanding due to "Usual Arithmetic Conversions" first `Temp` should be converted into `unsigned short`and result in `a` should be `0xF2`, but I am getting the response `0xF3` which means operation is performed with signed value of `Temp`. Please explain the behavior.

Is endianess also relevant in this scenario?

Comment: won't compile. `Temp2` undefined.

Comment: both `Temp` and `(unsigned short)Temp2` are promoted to int before doing the math. No operation in C can be done in types less than int

Comment: @Lưu Vĩnh Phúc Before doing the math, `(unsigned short)Temp2` is promoted to `int` or `unsigned`.  It depends on the range of types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, first all arguments to arithmetic operators are *promoted*, that is narrow types, such as your `short`s are converted to `int`. (at least on all common architectures).

Assuming `short` is 16 bit wide on your system, the initialization of `Temp` is implementation defined because the value of `0xF2C9` doesn't fit to the type. Most probably it is a negative value. Then, for the computation, that negative `signed short` value is promoted to `int`. The result of the division is a negative value, which then in turn is converted to `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if `INT_MAX >= USHRT_MAX`

The "Usual Arithmetic Conversions" convert `Temp` into `(int) Temp`.  This will only "extend the sign" if `int` is wider than `short`.

`((unsigned short)Temp2)` is promoted to `(int)((unsigned short)Temp2)` **or** `(unsigned)((unsigned short)Temp2)`.

If `INT_MAX >= USHRT_MAX`, then the division is done as `(int)/(int)`.

Otherwise, like on a 16-bit system, the division is done as `(int)/(unsigned)`, which is done as `(unsigned)/(unsigned)`.

---

[Edit]

`Temp`, initialized with `0xF2C9` (see note), likely has the value of -3383 (or has the value of 62153 should `short` unlikely be wider than 16 bits.)

With `(int)/(int)`, -3383/256 --> -13.21... --> -13.  -13 converted to `unsigned char` --> 256 - 13 --> 243 or 0xF3.

(Assuming 16-bit `int/unsigned`) With `(unsigned)/(unsigned)`, -3383 is converted to `unsigned` 65536 - 3383 --> 62153.  62153/256 --> 242.78... --> 242.  242 converted to `unsigned char` --> 242 or 0xF2.

Endian-ness in not relevant in this scenario.

---

Note: As pointed out by [@Jens Gustedt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27253636/2410359), the value in `Temp` is implementation defined when `Temp` is 16-bit.

Answer (score 0):

integer division works with "truncation toward zero", so the result of this division is `F3`, which is -13, instead of `F2`, which is -14. if you calculate this in decimal represenation the result would be -13.21 and then you would cut the .21.

Comment: This answer assumes calculations are performed on signed integers. The question asked **why** the integers are signed, so the answer doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

"The question asked *why* the integers are signed"

"As per my understanding due to "Usual Arithmetic Conversions" first Temp should be converted into unsigned short..." **NO**. You are wrong here. The signed short Temp has its high bit set, hence is negative. The bit gets extended to the left when converted to int. The signed short Temp2 does not have its high bt set; the cast to (unsigned short) has no effect; it is converted to a positive int. The negative int is now divided by the positive int, resulting in a negtive value.

In the conversion of Temp2 to int, you don't want the sign bit extended. Use:

```
a = (unsigned char)(((unsigned short)Temp)/Temp2);
```

(I didn't test it; just theory)

Answer (score 0):

Jens ,Paul and Mch,

Thanks for your clarification. But as per "ISO/IEC 9899 section 6.3.1.1

```
The rank of any unsigned integer type shall equal the rank of the corresponding
signed integer type, if any.
```

and as per 6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions" following rules should be applicable.

```
If both operands have the same type, then no further conversion is needed.

Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.

**Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
integer type.**

Otherwise, if the type of the operand with signed integer type can represent
all of the values of the type of the operand with unsigned integer type, then
the operand with unsigned integer type is converted to the type of the
operand with signed integer type.

Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned integer type
corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer type
```

so according to the above mentioned rule 3 1st **signed short** (integer type) should be converted in to **unsigned short** (integer type) and then arithmatic operation should be performed and result should be 0xF2.